# Django - Display list of category belonging to each card

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a Giftcard model, and Category model which holds all category, rate and term for each card. It has a foreign key back to Giftcard.

I just want to be able to list category, rate and terms for each Giftcard. As the code is right now, it displays the displays same category, rate and terms for all Giftcard.

model

```
class Giftcard(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
card_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Giftcard', blank=False)
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)



class Category(models.Model):
category = models.CharField(max_length=250)
name = models.ForeignKey(Giftcard, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="specs")
rate = models.IntegerField()
terms = models.TextField()
```

Here is my views

```
def giftcard(request):
giftcards = Giftcard.objects.filter(publish=True)

context = {
    'giftcards': giftcards,
}

return render(request, 'dashboard/giftcard.html', context)
```

Here is my template

```
{% for giftcard in giftcards %}
          <!-- Card -->
          <div class="col-lg-4 gift__card col-6 p-0">
            <a type="button" class="btn">
              <img class="img-fluid gift__card-img" src="{{ giftcard.card_image.url }}">
            </a>

            <div class="container d-flex align-items-center  justify-content-center">
              <div class="gift__card-modal-container py-5">
                <div class="card__container">
                  <div class="gift__card-overlay"></div>
                  <div class="container-fluid bg-light  gift__card-modal shadow-lg">
                    <div class="pop p-5">
                      <div class="row d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                        <div class="col-lg-5 col-12 p-0 m-0">
                          <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ giftcard.card_image.url }}">
                          <p class="text-muted">Select the card category and the amount.</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 card-details">
                          <form class="card-form">
                            <div class="form-group py-2">
                              <label for="card-category">Card category</label>
                              <input list="category" class="form-control" name="category" id="card_category"
                                placeholder="Select card category">

                              {% for spec in giftcard.specs.all %}
                              <datalist id="category">
                                <option value="{{ spec.category }}">{{ spec.category }}</option>
                              </datalist>
                              {% endfor %}
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group py-2">
                              <label for="Amount">Amount</label>
                              <div class="d-flex align-items-center amount">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount"
                                  placeholder="Please enter amount">
                                <span class="">#100,000</span>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group py-3">
                              {% for spec in giftcard.specs.all %}
                              <label for="rate">Current rate - {{ spec.rate }}</label>
                              {% endfor %}
                            </div>

                            <div class="border-none pt-2 pl-3 d-flex justify-content-end">
                              <button type="button" class="btn  process-card-btn">Proceed</button>
                            </div>
                          </form>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                


                <div class="gift__terms-card hide fade" id="terms" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                  aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content terms">
                      <div class="p-5">
                        <h4 class="terms-title pb-4">Trading terms</h4>
                        {% for spec in giftcard.specs.all %}
                        <p class="pb-2">
                          {{ spec.terms }}
                        </p>
                        {% endfor %}

                        <div class="border-none pt-3 pl-3 d-flex justify-content-end">
                          <button type="button" class="btn process-card-btn">Proceed</button>
                        </div>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
```

Comment: ForeignKey is a ManyToOne.  The way you have it now, Many Categories share One Giftcard.  Unless that is what you want, the ForeignKey should be in the GiftCard class.

Comment: it won't work that way because a giftcard can have more than one category

Comment: Please i need help, am new to Django

Comment: A GiftCard can have more than one Category, got it.  Can a Category have more than one GiftCard?

Comment: No, Category cannot have more than one Giftcard

Comment: add field `categories` and using `ManyToMany` relation, link to `Category` table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [django-doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey),you have to make `ForeginKey` field in your main `Giftcard` table which will do `ManyToOne` relation with `Category` table.

Try this:

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    rate = models.IntegerField()
    terms = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category


class Giftcard(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    card_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Giftcard/', blank=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    gift_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
def giftcard(request):
    giftcards = Giftcard.objects.filter(publish=True)

    context = {
        'giftcards': giftcards
    }
    return render(request, 'dashboard/giftcard.html', context)
```

Now, you can access all the properties of `Category` table in `Giftcard` items in your `template` file, and a `giftcard` can have more than one category, it is called `ManyToOne` relation,

> `Note:` you can also use `choices`, which is much better than making `table`, you can see that too here in [django-doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices).

#### Edit

Do this in `datalist`

```
<datalist id="category">
    {% for spec in giftcard.specs.all %}

        <option value="{{ spec.category }}">{{ spec.category }}</option>
    {% endfor %}

</datalist>
```

Comment: Is not working, please can i fix a meeting via google meet for you to check

Comment: why it is not working? What error did you get? What  do you want to do please clarify in question and edit the question rather than making too long comments, comments are used for clarification.

Comment: i updated my models according to yours and in my template i did this
 `<datalist id="category">
{% for spec in giftcard.category_set.all %}
<option value="Apple">{{ spec.rate }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</datalist>`.

Comment: I edited my answer according to your choice, check it.

Answer (score 0):

If, as you say in one of your comments, *"it won't work that way because a giftcard can have more than one category"* and *"No, Category cannot have more than one Giftcard"*, then your *original* models are correct, with ForeignKey in the Category class.  Second, I do not know what exactly is going on, perhaps add screenshots of what you are getting that is wrong, because I just tried your *original* code out, and it **works**, with the modifications to the `datalist` suggested by [@Sunderam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17562044/sunderam-dubey).  Test this out in your html template:

```html
{% for giftcard in giftcards %}
    {% for spec in giftcard.specs.all %}
        {{ spec.terms }}<br>
        {{ spec.category }}<br>
        {{ spec.rate }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

When I did this, I am seeing different terms, categories and rates for each.  Again, is this not what you want?

**Edit**
You must understand that the datalist will have *all* the `spec` values, and one shows up when you start typing in the input box.  for example, if you type `c`, then the list will pop up with *all* categories that begin with `c`.

**Edit**
Make sure the datalist has been changed to

```html
<div class="form-group py-2">
  <label for="card-category">Card category</label>
  <input list="category" class="form-control" name="category" id="card_category"
    placeholder="Select card category">

  {% for spec in giftcard.specs.all %}
  <datalist id="category">
    <option value="{{ spec.category }}">{{ spec.category }}</option>
  </datalist>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

After all, you want only *one* `<datalist>` element, and then *many* `<option>`s.

Comment: Here is my front end, everything is work fine except getting the category
https://i.stack.imgur.com/grwug.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxEcR.png

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "getting the category". It seems to be working just fine for me. Did you change the datalist. Check out my edited answer. Best of luck. @cedars